# SPF record not being detected by gmail

Tags: spf

I recently added SPF record to my server & it passes all the results required.

However sending email doesn't detect SPF record. The method I use to detect is whether gmail shows 'mailed-by'.

I use my own email server along with google's to include google apps features & this is the only spf record I have on my server.

SPF record is:

```
v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com ip4:X.X.X.X ~all
```

Is this because it takes some time to propagate the changes made in DNS file? Or is there something else I'm missing?

**ISSUE EDITED**

While seeing 'Show Original' menu from gmail, it gets me this:

```
Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning noreply@example.com
does not designate 64.202.189.129 as permitted sender) client-ip=64.202.189.129;
```

Issue is the client ip mentioned above is changing in every email I receive even though I use SMTP relay from my server.

I talked with GoDaddy support & they said, ip will always change. There is no way it can use static ip for sending email.

What can be the possible solution to this?

Comment: TTL could certainly be an issue.  Have you tried going to a site such as mxtoolbox.com to test your config?

Comment: I just tried http://network-tools.com & it's showing SPF record correctly.

Comment: In Gmail, click "show original" from the dropdown menu next to the reply button on a message. Then hit ctrl+f in the window that opens and search for SPF. You can use the information it gives there to narrow down what Gmail thinks is going on with SPF.

Comment: What's the domain?

Comment: Okay, gotcha. It's sending email from another ip address I'm unaware about. I think yes that's the issue. Let me try another one.

Comment: Please see the issueI'm having now, I edited my question

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending email from GoDaddy from your site or applications, you have two options:

- Change your site/applications to use a mail relay you already trust.
- Include GoDaddy's IP ranges that are used for SMTP in your SPF record

If you're a Google Apps customer, the best option is to configure your site/applications to send email through Gmail (as usual), or [use Google Apps SMTP Relay](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491?hl=en). Using the SMTP Relay feature you can have your mail server relay through Google too for example.

If however you'd prefer to authorize all of GoDaddy's servers to send email on your behalf, you should contact GoDaddy support and ask for their preferred method of authorizing their SMTP servers in your SPF record.

Note that SPF alone is unable to prevent having your domain spoofed by spammers/phishers. Google recommends that Google Apps customers [deploy DMARC](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2466580?hl=en) which relies on both SPF and DKIM to combat domain spoofing.

DMARC can break some mailing list software. However [some mailing list software providers/packages](https://dmarc.org/resources/products-and-services/#MLMs) have already rolled out DMARC support. An in particular services like Yahoo Groups and Google Groups fully support DMARC without any changes required.

Additionally, [Authenticated Received Chain (ARC)](http://arc-spec.org/) is being drafted to allow intermediaries and final recipients to authenticate the original authentication results as they saw them before the intermediate software manipulated the message. That should allow any outstanding mailing list packages to fully support DMARC.

**EDITED:** added information on mailing list impact.

Comment: Be aware that DMARC violates the RFCs on well-behaved mailing lists. If you publish DMARC records for your domain, and check DMARC on incoming email, you will break your users' ability to subscribe to mailing lists.

Comment: In response to edit: Marco is right that mailing list software has tried to work around DMARC's unilateral brokenness, but it's wrong to describe it as "DMARC support".  It is impossible for a mailing list to both (a) comply with RFC5322's prohibition on changing the `From:` header, and (b) deliver list postings from domains which publish restrictive DMARC records, to recipients which check DMARC inbound.  At best one can try to kludge round DMARC, which is why (eg) the mailman team describe their new release as ...

Comment: ... having [features to help with mitigation of the impacts of
DMARC on mailing lists](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-announce/2014-May/000193.html), rather than having "*DMARC support*", in the announcement linked from Marco's pointer to DMARC support, above.